# Three.js: Raycasting with Points, InstancedBufferGeometry, and RawShaderMaterial (GPU Picking)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a scene in which I'm using Points, InstancedBufferGeometry, and a RawShaderMaterial. I'd like to add raycasting to the scene, such that when a point is clicked I can figure out which point was clicked.

In previous scenes [[example](https://bl.ocks.org/duhaime/fc8d8918f23cedd6660a4cc3279b5aa0)], I've been able to determine which point was clicked by accessing the `.index` attribute of the match returned by the `raycaster.intersectObject()` call. With the geometry and material below, though, the index is always `0`.

Does anyone know how I can determine which of the points was clicked in the scene below? Any help others can offer on this question would be very appreciated.

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; }
body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://rawgit.com/YaleDHLab/pix-plot/master/assets/js/trackball-controls.js'></script>

  <script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertex-shader'>
  /**
  * The vertex shader's main() function must define `gl_Position`,
  * which describes the position of each vertex in screen coordinates.
  *
  * To do so, we can use the following variables defined by Three.js:
  *   attribute vec3 position - stores each vertex's position in world space
  *   attribute vec2 uv - sets each vertex's the texture coordinates
  *   uniform mat4 projectionMatrix - maps camera space into screen space
  *   uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix - combines:
  *     model matrix: maps a point's local coordinate space into world space
  *     view matrix: maps world space into camera space
  *
  * `attributes` can vary from vertex to vertex and are defined as arrays
  *   with length equal to the number of vertices. Each index in the array
  *   is an attribute for the corresponding vertex. Each attribute must
  *   contain n_vertices * n_components, where n_components is the length
  *   of the given datatype (e.g. for a vec2, n_components = 2; for a float,
  *   n_components = 1)
  * `uniforms` are constant across all vertices
  * `varyings` are values passed from the vertex to the fragment shader
  *
  * For the full list of uniforms defined by three, see:
  *   https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram
  **/

  // set float precision
  precision mediump float;

  // specify geometry uniforms
  uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
  uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

  // to get the camera attributes:
  uniform vec3 cameraPosition;

  // blueprint attributes
  attribute vec3 position; // sets the blueprint's vertex positions

  // instance attributes
  attribute vec3 translation; // x y translation offsets for an instance

  void main() {
    // set point position
    vec3 pos = position + translation;
    vec4 projected = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projected;

    // use the delta between the point position and camera position to size point
    float xDelta = pow(projected[0] - cameraPosition[0], 2.0);
    float yDelta = pow(projected[1] - cameraPosition[1], 2.0);
    float zDelta = pow(projected[2] - cameraPosition[2], 2.0);
    float delta  = pow(xDelta + yDelta + zDelta, 0.5);
    gl_PointSize = 10000.0 / delta;
  }
  </script>

  <script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
  /**
  * The fragment shader's main() function must define `gl_FragColor`,
  * which describes the pixel color of each pixel on the screen.
  *
  * To do so, we can use uniforms passed into the shader and varyings
  * passed from the vertex shader.
  *
  * Attempting to read a varying not generated by the vertex shader will
  * throw a warning but won't prevent shader compiling.
  **/

  precision highp float;

  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
  </script>

<script>

/**
* Generate a scene object with a background color
**/

function getScene() {
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xaaaaaa);
  return scene;
}

/**
* Generate the camera to be used in the scene. Camera args:
*   [0] field of view: identifies the portion of the scene
*     visible at any time (in degrees)
*   [1] aspect ratio: identifies the aspect ratio of the
*     scene in width/height
*   [2] near clipping plane: objects closer than the near
*     clipping plane are culled from the scene
*   [3] far clipping plane: objects farther than the far
*     clipping plane are culled from the scene
**/

function getCamera() {
  var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 100000);
  camera.position.set(0, 1, -6000);
  return camera;
}

/**
* Generate the renderer to be used in the scene
**/

function getRenderer() {
  // Create the canvas with a renderer
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  // Add support for retina displays
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  // Specify the size of the canvas
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  // Add the canvas to the DOM
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  return renderer;
}

/**
* Generate the controls to be used in the scene
* @param {obj} camera: the three.js camera for the scene
* @param {obj} renderer: the three.js renderer for the scene
**/

function getControls(camera, renderer) {
  var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
  controls.panSpeed = 0.4;
  return controls;
}

/**
* Set the current mouse coordinates {-1:1}
* @param {Event} event - triggered on canvas mouse move
**/

function onMousemove(event) {
  mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
}

/**
* Store the previous mouse position so that when the next
* click event registers we can tell whether the user
* is clicking or dragging.
* @param {Event} event - triggered on canvas mousedown
**/

function onMousedown(event) {
  lastMouse.copy(mouse);
}

/**
* Callback for mouseup events on the window. If the user
* clicked an image, zoom to that image.
* @param {Event} event - triggered on canvas mouseup
**/

function onMouseup(event) {
  var selected = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
  console.log(selected)
}

// add event listeners for the canvas
function addCanvasListeners() {
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMousemove, false)
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMousedown, false)
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseup, false)
}

/**
* Generate the points for the scene
* @param {obj} scene: the current scene object
**/

function addPoints(scene) {
  // this geometry builds a blueprint and many copies of the blueprint
  var geometry  = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();

  geometry.addAttribute( 'position',
    new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array( [0, 0, 0] ), 3));

  // add data for each observation
  var n = 10000; // number of observations
  var rootN = n**(1/2);
  var cellSize = 20;
  var translation = new Float32Array( n * 3 );
  var translationIterator = 0;
  var unit = 0;

  for (var i=0; i<n*3; i++) {
    switch (i%3) {
      case 0: // x dimension
        translation[translationIterator++] = (unit % rootN) * cellSize;
        break;
      case 1: // y dimension
        translation[translationIterator++] = Math.floor(unit / rootN) * cellSize;
        break;
      case 2: // z dimension
        translation[translationIterator++] = 0;
        break;
    }
    if (i % 3 == 0) unit++;
  }

  geometry.addAttribute( 'translation',
    new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute( translation, 3, 1 ) );

  var material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent,
  });
  var mesh = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
  mesh.frustumCulled = false; // prevent the mesh from being clipped on drag
  scene.add(mesh);
}

/**
* Render!
**/

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  controls.update();
};

/**
* Main
**/

var scene = getScene();
var camera = getCamera();
var renderer = getRenderer();
var controls = getControls(camera, renderer);
// raycasting
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
raycaster.params.Points.threshold = 10000;
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var lastMouse = new THREE.Vector2();
addCanvasListeners();
// main
addPoints(scene);
render();

</script>
```

Comment: Consider how many _actual_ points you're creating (the `position` attribute), and how `Points` would index that. Instances aren't real, they're clones of an original, and your original has an index of `0`, always. The raycaster is unaware of the special nature of the other points because it knows nothing about `InstancedBufferGeometry`/`InstancedBufferAttribute`. You will likely need to override the `Points.raycast` method and take your `translation` attribute into account to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks @TheJim01! Time to roll up my sleeves I guess. If you have any notions on how one might proceed in this case I'd be grateful for any insights you can offer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to use the technique sometimes referred to as *GPU Picking*.

First study https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu.html.

Once you understand the concept, study https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_instances_gpu.html.

Another solution is to replicate on the CPU the instancing logic implemented on the GPU. You would do so in your `raycast()` method. Whether it is worth it depends on the complexity of your use case.

three.js r.95

Comment: @WestLandley thanks very much for your answer. Just to make sure I understand, does the second solution you propose here (replicating the instanced geom layout on the CPU) mean modifying the raycaster internals, or just building a BufferGeometry and feeding *that* to the default raycaster? Also, I'm planning to render 1M+ points; should that lead me to adopt one of these strategies over the other?

Comment: GPU Picking would be reasonable in that case, but you could also study the three.js octree raycasting example if you want to do picking on the cpu.

Comment: thanks for following up. If you have a moment, can I please ask you if I'm right to think the second method you propose above would mean creating my instanced geometry again as a non-instanced geometry, then (without rendering the non-instanced geometry) feeding that non-instanced geometry to the raycaster? If I've misunderstood, I'd be grateful for any additional pointers you can offer on the CPU raycasting method hinted at above...

Comment: @duhaime You wouldn't need to recreate your geometry, but you'd need to transform a bounding sphere around in space based on your instanced attribute. For each transformation, update the bounding sphere (position and radius), then raycast against it. For 1 million points, that could get expensive, even with an octree. My knee-jerk is to go for GPU picking because it's just pushing a new color buffer to the GPU, and you'll be able to ID _all_ visible points, not just the ones you're raycasting against.

Comment: @WestLangley TheJim01 do groups complicate the GPU Picking story? All of my meshes belong to one group currently -- will that affect the way I need to implement the GPU Picking? If not I'm missing something somewhere else...

Comment: @duhaime If you have additional questions, please make a new post and provide sufficient details for your problem to be replicated.

Answer (score 1):

In case others end up in this same boat in the future, here's a quick sketch of what worked in this case [[block](https://bl.ocks.org/duhaime/1eafa293e7ce16b074a6d55cac67badc)]:

```js
/**
* Generate a scene object with a background color
**/

function getScene() {
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xaaaaaa);
  return scene;
}

/**
* Generate the camera to be used in the scene. Camera args:
*   [0] field of view: identifies the portion of the scene
*     visible at any time (in degrees)
*   [1] aspect ratio: identifies the aspect ratio of the
*     scene in width/height
*   [2] near clipping plane: objects closer than the near
*     clipping plane are culled from the scene
*   [3] far clipping plane: objects farther than the far
*     clipping plane are culled from the scene
**/

function getCamera() {
  var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 100000);
  camera.position.set(0, 1, -6000);
  return camera;
}

/**
* Generate the renderer to be used in the scene
**/

function getRenderer() {
  // Create the canvas with a renderer
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  // Add support for retina displays
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  // Specify the size of the canvas
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  // Add the canvas to the DOM
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  return renderer;
}

/**
* Generate the controls to be used in the scene
* @param {obj} camera: the three.js camera for the scene
* @param {obj} renderer: the three.js renderer for the scene
**/

function getControls(camera, renderer) {
  var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
  controls.panSpeed = 0.4;
  return controls;
}

/**
* Generate the points for the scene
* @param {obj} scene: the current scene object
**/

function addPoints(scene) {
  // this geometry builds a blueprint and many copies of the blueprint
  var geometry  = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();
  var BA = THREE.BufferAttribute;
  var IBA = THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute;

  // add data for each observation
  var n = 10000; // number of observations
  var rootN = n**(1/2);
  var unit = 0;
  var cellSize = 20;
  var color = new THREE.Color();
  var translations = new Float32Array( n * 3 );
  var colors = new Float32Array( n * 3 );
  var translationIterator = 0;
  var colorIterator = 0;

  for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    var rgb = color.setHex(i+1);
    translations[translationIterator++] = (i % rootN) * cellSize;
    translations[translationIterator++] = Math.floor(i / rootN) * cellSize;
    translations[translationIterator++] = 0;
    colors[colorIterator++] = rgb.r;
    colors[colorIterator++] = rgb.g;
    colors[colorIterator++] = rgb.b;
  }

  var positionAttr = new BA( new Float32Array( [0, 0, 0] ), 3);
  var translationAttr = new IBA(translations, 3, 1);
  var colorAttr = new IBA(colors, 3, 1);
  geometry.addAttribute('position', positionAttr);
  geometry.addAttribute('translation', translationAttr);
  geometry.addAttribute('color', colorAttr);
  var material = getMaterial({useColors: 1.0});
  var mesh = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
  mesh.frustumCulled = false; // prevent the mesh from being clipped on drag
  scene.add(mesh);
  pickingScene.add(mesh.clone());
}

function getMaterial(obj) {
  var material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
      useColor: {
        type: 'f',
        value: obj.useColors,
      }
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent,
  });
  return material;
}

/**
* Render!
**/

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  controls.update();
};

/**
* Main
**/

var scene = getScene();
var camera = getCamera();
var renderer = getRenderer();
var controls = getControls(camera, renderer);

// picking
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
var pickingScene = new THREE.Scene();
pickingTexture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(w, h);
pickingTexture.texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  renderer.render(pickingScene, camera, pickingTexture);
  var pixelBuffer = new Uint8Array(4);
  renderer.readRenderTargetPixels(
    pickingTexture, e.clientX, pickingTexture.height - e.clientY,
    1, 1, pixelBuffer );
  var id = (pixelBuffer[0]<<16)|(pixelBuffer[1]<<8)|(pixelBuffer[2]);
  if (id) {
    console.log(id, pixelBuffer);
    var elem = document.querySelector('#selected');
    elem.textContent = 'You are hovering on element number ' + (id-1);
  }
})

// main
addPoints(scene);
render();
```

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; }
body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#selected { position: absolute; top: 10; left: 10; }
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/95/three.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://rawgit.com/YaleDHLab/pix-plot/master/assets/js/trackball-controls.js'></script>

<div id='selected'></div>

<script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertex-shader'>
/**
* The vertex shader's main() function must define `gl_Position`,
* which describes the position of each vertex in screen coordinates.
*
* To do so, we can use the following variables defined by Three.js:
*   attribute vec3 position - stores each vertex's position in world space
*   attribute vec2 uv - sets each vertex's the texture coordinates
*   uniform mat4 projectionMatrix - maps camera space into screen space
*   uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix - combines:
*     model matrix: maps a point's local coordinate space into world space
*     view matrix: maps world space into camera space
*
* `attributes` can vary from vertex to vertex and are defined as arrays
*   with length equal to the number of vertices. Each index in the array
*   is an attribute for the corresponding vertex. Each attribute must
*   contain n_vertices * n_components, where n_components is the length
*   of the given datatype (e.g. for a vec2, n_components = 2; for a float,
*   n_components = 1)
* `uniforms` are constant across all vertices
* `varyings` are values passed from the vertex to the fragment shader
*
* For the full list of uniforms defined by three, see:
*   https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram
**/

precision mediump float;

uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform vec3 cameraPosition;

attribute vec3 position;    // blueprint's vertex positions
attribute vec3 color;       // only used for raycasting
attribute vec3 translation; // x y translation offsets for an instance

varying vec3 vColor;

void main() {
  vColor = color;

  // set point position
  vec3 pos = position + translation;
  vec4 projected = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
  gl_Position = projected;

  // use the delta between the point position and camera position to size point
  float xDelta = pow(projected[0] - cameraPosition[0], 2.0);
  float yDelta = pow(projected[1] - cameraPosition[1], 2.0);
  float zDelta = pow(projected[2] - cameraPosition[2], 2.0);
  float delta  = pow(xDelta + yDelta + zDelta, 0.5);
  gl_PointSize = 10000.0 / delta;
}
</script>

<script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
/**
* The fragment shader's main() function must define `gl_FragColor`,
* which describes the pixel color of each pixel on the screen.
*
* To do so, we can use uniforms passed into the shader and varyings
* passed from the vertex shader.
*
* Attempting to read a varying not generated by the vertex shader will
* throw a warning but won't prevent shader compiling.
**/

precision highp float;

varying vec3 vColor;

uniform float useColor;

void main() {
  if (useColor == 1.) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.0);
  } else {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
}
</script>
```